# Reverse a string of any length using pointers in C

Tags: c, string, reverse

I was just browsing through some interview questions and found this code to reverse a string using pointers. But I see that here they have defined char string[100] which limits the string length. I am not so good at C. How do I modify the same to make it a string of any length?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int string_length(char*);
void reverse(char*);

main() 
{
   char string[100];

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);

   reverse(string);

   printf("Reverse of entered string is \"%s\".\n", string);

   return 0;
}

void reverse(char *string) 
{
   int length, c;
   char *begin, *end, temp;

   length = string_length(string);

   begin = string;
   end = string;

   for ( c = 0 ; c < ( length - 1 ) ; c++ )
      end++;

   for ( c = 0 ; c < length/2 ; c++ ) 
   {        
      temp = *end;
      *end = *begin;
      *begin = temp;

      begin++;
      end--;
   }
}

int string_length(char *pointer)
{
   int c = 0;

   while( *(pointer+c) != '\0' )
      c++;

   return c;
}
```

Comment: Could this help perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505451/how-to-read-unlimited-characters-in-c

Comment: you can use the `length`(result of `string_length`) for `end`.

Comment: This is not a "reverse string" question as this part is fine, it's reading the string question.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`; it is not in C2011 and cannot be used safely.  Use `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of static array use dynamic memory allocation: `char *tab = malloc(n * sizeof(char))` where `n` is some variable representing desired length.

Comment: It is not that easy. This will still limit the amount of characters that can be read. The memory is just put somewhere else (on the heap instead of the stack).

Comment: But it definitelly pushes the limit. Ultimate solution would be to read input from file and write output to file, but I doubt it is desired solution.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Can you kindly explain how it will still limit the amount of characters that can be read?Can't n be arbitrary?

Comment: @BartFriederichs You mean limited by the total memory available right?

Comment: @SheerFish yes `n` can be arbitrary, but it is still a limit. The question wants **any** size. I'll read that as limited by hardware, not software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use malloc() for this purpose if you want the size to be decided/inputted by the user at runtime.

[malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic memory allocation is the solution.. 
Take a pointer to the string and allocate the memory dynamically.. this allocates at run time..
This will solve your problem..

```
char *str;
str = (char*)malloc(n *sizeof(char));
```

NOTE: typecasting is optional in C and 'n' here is the required length.(can be user input).